# How can I make a function which has a multidimensional array input, transforms it, and ouputs the new multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

### Input & Output

**Back story**

*(my English isn't the best)*

Hey, I'm trying to build a game that will teach children about words and letters.
Im making it with HTML/CSS & JS(little JQuery) and a little PHP.
I have to build a tree that holds leaves with letters inside it. I want to build lots of levels, but I would have to type a very big array myself(and I know it should be possible to do it automatically).

I would really appreciate some help!

---

**Problem**

I have a multidimensional array which looks like this:

```
var words = [
    [
        ['SNEL'],
        ['WORD'],
        ['TIJD'],
        ['BORD'],
        [etc]
    ],
    [
        [BORDE]
        [etc]
    ],
    [
        etc
    ],
    [
        ['BEWUSTER']
    ]
];
```

Im trying to build a function that will output this into:

```
var modifiedWords1 = [
    [
        ['img/Letters_normal/S.png', 'img/Letters_normal/N.png', 'img/Letters_normal/E.png', 'img/Letters_normal/L.png'],
        ['img/Letters_normal/W.png', 'img/Letters_normal/O.png', 'img/Letters_normal/R.png', 'img/Letters_normal/D.png'],
        [img/Letters_normal/etc]
    ],
    [
        ['img/Letters_normal/B.png', 'img/Letters_normal/O.png', 'img/Letters_normal/R.png', 'img/Letters_normal/D.png', 'img/Letters_normal/E.png']
        [etc]
    ],
    [
        etc
    ],
    [
        ['img/Letters_normal/B.png', 'img/Letters_normal/E.png', 'img/Letters_normal/W.png', 'img/Letters_normal/U.png', 'img/Letters_normal/S.png', 'img/Letters_normal/T.png', 'img/Letters_normal/E.png', 'img/Letters_normal/R.png']
    ]
];
```

And this:

```
var Modifiedwords2 = [
    [
        ['S.png', 'N.png', 'E.png', 'L.png'],
        ['W.png', 'O.png', 'R.png', 'D.png'],
        ['T.png', 'I.png', 'J.png', 'D.png'],
        ['B.png', 'O.png', 'R.png', 'D.png'],
        [etc]
    ],
    [
        ['B.png', 'O.png', 'R.png', 'D.png', 'E.png']
        [etc]
    ],
    [
        etc
    ],
    [
        ['B.png', 'E.png', 'W.png', 'U.png', 'S.png', 'T.png', 'E.png', 'R.png']
    ]
];
```

---

Sorry for my bad english, but thanks in advance!
Feel free to ask anything!

Comment: What are `words`? Any 4-letter combinations (no pun intended)?

Comment: You're approaching this the wrong way. Keep a multidimensional array of the letters and then add an additional parameter for the path to functions that need it, keep your code **and** your data DRY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we don't know what you have done so far, this is an approach using the native [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method which is very useful to understand. It allows you to iterate over an array and return a new array that has the same number of elements that have possibly been transformed by the supplied function.

```js
var words = [
  [
    ["SNEL"],
    ["WORD"],
    ["TIJD"],
    ["BORD"]
  ],
  [
    ["BORDE"]
  ],
  [
    ["BEWUSTER"]
  ]
];

var modifiedWords1 = modifyWords(words, 'img/Letters_normal/');
var modifiedWords2 = modifyWords(words);

document.write(
  "<h3>modifiedWords1:</h3>" +
  "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(modifiedWords1, null, 4) + "</pre>" + 
  "<h3>modifiedWords2:</h3>" +
  "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(modifiedWords2, null, 4) + "</pre>"
);

// Uses:
// modifyWords([...], 'some/prefix/to/use/', '.someSuffixToUse');
// modifyWords([...], undefined, '.someSuffixToUse');
// modifyWords([...], 'some/prefix/to/use/'); // suffix would be '.png'
// modifyWords([...]); // suffix would be '.png'
function modifyWords(arr, prefix, suffix) {
  // default prefix to ''
  prefix = prefix || '';
  // default suffix to '.png'
  suffix = suffix || '.png';

  return arr.map(function mapInputArray(list) {
    return list.map(function mapWordArray(word) {
      // Create an array from a string by splitting with an empty string
      return word[0].split('').map(function mapLetterArray(letter) {
        return prefix + letter + suffix;
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `Array.prototype.map()` , `String.prototype.split()`

```js
var words = [
  [
    ["SNEL"],
    ["WORD"],
    ["TIJD"],
    ["BORD"],
    ["etc"]
  ],
  [
    ["BORDE"],
    ["etc"]
  ],
  [
    ["etc"]
  ],
  [
    ["BEWUSTER"]
  ]
];

var modifyWords = function(arr, mod, beforeAfter) {
  return arr.map(function(val, key) {
    return val.map(function(v, k) {
      return v[0].split("").map(function(value, index) {
        return mod && beforeAfter 
               ? beforeAfter === "before" 
                 ? mod + value : value + mod
               : value
      })
    })
  });
};

var modifiedWords1 = modifyWords(words, "img/Letters_normal/", "before");
var modifiedWords2 = modifyWords(words, ".png", "after");

console.log("modifiedWords1:", modifiedWords1
            , "modifiedWords2:", modifiedWords2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a little recursion to tackle the problem:

```
function isArray(arg) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(arg) === '[object Array]';
}

function process(arr, beforeStr, afterStr) {
    beforeStr = beforeStr || '';
    afterStr = afterStr || '';
    var len = arr.length;
    var copy = new Array(len);
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if(isArray(arr[i])) {
            copy[i] = process(arr[i], beforeStr, afterStr);
        } else {
            var letters = arr[i].split('');
            for(j = 0; j < letters.length; j++) {
                letters[j] = beforeStr + letters[j] + afterStr;
            }
            return letters;
        }
    }
    return copy;
}

var processed = process(words, '/some/path/name/', '.png');
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dgrundel/17g2u1p4/